# How to use pose for `move_base` to produce `cmd_vel`?

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the Wiki page of `move_base`, it seems that `move_base` obtains the pose estimation of a robot by a `tf` from `map` to `odom`, which is often published by `amcl`. However, in my application, I use a motion predictor to predict the future pose of the robot, and I want to use that *future pose as a basis for my `move_base`* computation (i.e. use the future pose instead of the current pose estimated by `amcl`).

The message of my future pose is `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped`, which is not a tf. How do I control the robot using `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped` instead of tf for `move_base`?

There are several solutions that I have tried:

1. One alternative is to replace the tf publisher in `amcl` with a custom tf publisher (from `map` to `odom`) using the future pose, but it causes the laser scan misaligned.
2. Another alternative is to keep the original `amcl` code unchanged, and write a tf publisher (from `map` to `odom_future` frame) using the future pose . This approach seems realistic, because it does not affect localization and sensor readings, but I could not find the pieces of code in `move_base` to expect the frame `odom_future` instead of `odom`.

Could somebody provide me some guidance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294593/how-to-use-pose-for-%60move_base%60-to-produce-%60cmd_vel%60?/) by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your second approach seems to be the better one. `move_base` (or more precisely the `navigation_stack`) utilizes [costmap_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) for its planning "computation", and it uses the robot's base frame as the current pose of the robot. Fortunately you can adjust that by setting the `robot_base_frame` parameter of both the global and local costmap configuration, or by simply include it in the common configuration. Just set `robot_base_frame` to your `odom_future` and that should be it.

See here for more detail : http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Costmap_Configuration_.28local_costmap.29_.26_.28global_costmap.29

---

Originally posted by [mathsci](https://answers.ros.org/users/35967/mathsci/) with karma: 41 on 2018-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) on 2018-06-21**:
Hi @mathsci, your suggestion works fine at the end. However, I wonder how to compute the tf from map to odom based on a pose estimation? I've searched online for quite a while, but couldn't find how it is done. I looked at the `amcl_node.cpp` file but it doesn't make much sense.